# Split / Slice column values (text data) into multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have following dataframe

```py
data = [
    ['ticket_1', '''2021-04-18 11:11:23 - Unknown
Part replaced

2021-04-18 09:03:10 - John Doe
Requires part change. Technician enroute

2021-04-17 19:30:25 - John Doe
Working on the issue'''], 
    ['ticket_2','''2021-04-17 19:13:09 - Unknown_2
Transferring to other resource

2021-04-17 19:12:34 - Unknown_2
Issue assigned''']
]
```

[image: original dataframe]

I would like to split the comments column and perform below steps

**1. Extract date time and include in another column**

**2. Have string after date time in another column**

**3. Duplicate ticket_num based on multiple date time in comments column**

For example

```
data_1 = [
    ['ticket_1','''2021-04-18 11:11:23''','''Unknown
Part replaced'''],
    ['ticket_1', '''2021-04-18 09:03:10''', '''John Doe
Requires part change. Technician enroute'''],
    ['ticket_1','''2021-04-17 19:30:25''', '''John Doe
Working on the issue'''],
    ['ticket_2','''2021-04-17 19:13:09''','''Unknown_2
Transferring to other resource'''],
    ['ticket_2','''2021-04-17 19:12:34''','''Unknown_2
Issue assigned''']
]
```

[image: desired output]

I have tried using combinations of regex, explode, split and slice but not getting fruitful results.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the dataframe has following structure:

```py
  ticket_num                                                                                                                                                                      comments
0   ticket_1  2021-04-18 11:11:23 - Unknown\nPart replaced\n2021-04-18 09:03:10 - John Doe\nRequires part change. Technician enroute\n2021-04-17 19:30:25 - John Doe\nWorking on the issue
1   ticket_2                                                              2021-04-17 19:13:09 - Unknown_2\nTransferring to other resource\n2021-04-17 19:12:34 - Unknown_2\nIssue assigned
```

Start by finding all the occurances of the string values in `comments` column on datetime value followed by any character until next datetime value or the end of the multiline string i.e. `\Z`, using `Series.str.split`, and passing the proper regex. You also need to pass `re.DOTALL` flag since it's a multiline string, then `explode` the dataframe on this new columns, and convert the value of datetime and comment to two separate columns applying pandas Series on them, and performing the concatenation on `axis=1`:

```py
df['extracted'] = (df['comments']
                    .str
                    .findall('(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})(.*?(?=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}|\Z))',
                            flags=re.DOTALL)
                   )
df  = df.explode('extracted')
df = pd.concat([df, df['extracted'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x, index=['datetime',  'comment']))], axis=1)
```

You can now drop the unwanted columns, and also strip off the new `comment` column to remove any hyphen `-` and white spaces at the beginning or the end, and if needed, you can also convert `datetime` column to pandas datetime type.

**OUTPUT:**

```py
>>> df[['ticket_num', 'datetime',  'comment']]

  ticket_num             datetime                                                comment
0   ticket_1  2021-04-18 11:11:23                             - Unknown\nPart replaced\n 
0   ticket_1  2021-04-18 09:03:10 - John Doe\nRequires part change. Technician enroute\n 
0   ticket_1  2021-04-17 19:30:25                       - John Doe\nWorking on the issue 
1   ticket_2  2021-04-17 19:13:09          - Unknown_2\nTransferring to other resource\n 
1   ticket_2  2021-04-17 19:12:34                            - Unknown_2\nIssue assigned
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Thanks for the explanation as well